# topViewController: unrecognized selector error with custome segue to navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to use "Slideout Sidebar" from this [github](https://github.com/appcoda/Slideout-Sidebar-Demo) solution.

this my storyboard :

[image]

Im using lazy loading method for my Uicollectionview so in my delegate

code i have this :

```
   ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;

    parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
        if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           myCollectionViewController *rootViewControllers = (myCollectionViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
 [weakParser.appRecordList valueForKey:@"id"]);
                rootViewControllers.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
                if(weakParser.appRecordList == nil)
                     NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is nill");
                if(weakParser.appRecordList != nil)
                    NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is Not nil  l");

               [rootViewControllers.collectionView reloadData];

            });
        }
```

if i run my project after modification it returns this error :

```
    2015-03-06 19:57:23.763 News[4995:51611] -[SWRevealViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd5bd3c280
    2015-03-06 19:57:28.785 News[4995:51611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd5bd3c280'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b0ff35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067a8bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b1704d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a6f27c ___forwarding___ + 988
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a6ee18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   News                          0x0000000103481b2a __51-

[LazyTableAppDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:]_block_invoke_2213 + 106
```

if i comment out the code section inside Parsoperation the view and slidebar works perfectly but collectionview new data not showing up , so i guess the topcontroller after modification isnt "topViewController" 
anymore.

ive tried this code inside block for custome segue but nothing happend:

```
            UIStoryboardSegue * segue;
            UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
            myCollectionViewController *rootViewControllers = (myCollectionViewController*)[navController topViewController];
```

tried this one too (have data inside class of collectionview but numberofitemsinsection not getting called):

```
   ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    myCollectionViewController *svc =[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainCategory"];
    parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
        if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                svc.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
                    [svc.collectionView reloadData];



            });
        }
```

Comment: `self.window.rootViewController` is your `SWRevealViewController` object.

Comment: can u please elaborate? how can i refresh my collection view now after my self.window.rootViewController object changed ?